# Tkinter app does not update timer smoothly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am pretty new to using Tkinter and I am trying to build an app that displays a timer as one of its features.  I am updating a label to display the time from a separate thread.  On the display the time does not update smoothly.  It freezes for short periods of time and then jumps a second or more.  It there a way to keep the updates consistent so the timer is smooth?

It's a simple app so far so it doesn't seem like the CPU or main thread should be busy doing anything else.  When you press a button it starts a separate thread that periodically sets the label text.  I've tried sleeping between 0-0.1 seconds per update and the result is the same.

```
window = tk.Tk()
frame2 = tk.Frame(master=window, width=50, height=50, bg="yellow")
frame2.pack()

time_display = tk.Label(master=frame2, text="0.0")
time_display.pack()

update_thread = None


def play_pause():
    global update_thread, stop_loop
    if not update_thread:
        stop_loop = False
        update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_timer_loop)
        update_thread.start()
    else:
        stop_loop = True
        update_thread = None


stop_loop = False

def update_timer_loop():
    global window
    start = time.time()
    base_time = float(time_display["text"])
    while not stop_loop:
        current_time = time.time() - start + base_time
        window.after(0, lambda: set_text(round(current_time, 2)))
        time.sleep(0.1)


def set_text(text):
    time_display["text"] = text

btn_play = tk.Button(master=frame1, text="Play/Pause", command=play_pause)
btn_play.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need threading at all in this. I see you tried to use after, and that's the correct approach. The only thing extra to know is that you can use `after_cancel` to cancel an upcoming event that you scheduled with `after`. Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

window = tk.Tk()

time_display = tk.Label(window, text="0.0")
time_display.pack()

update_thread = None

def play_pause():
    global update_thread, start, base_time
    if update_thread is None:
        start = time.time()
        base_time = float(time_display["text"])
        update_timer_loop() # start the loop
    else:
        time_display.after_cancel(update_thread)
        update_thread = None

def update_timer_loop():
    global update_thread
    current_time = time.time() - start + base_time
    time_display["text"] = round(current_time, 2)
    update_thread = window.after(100, update_timer_loop)

btn_play = tk.Button(master=window, text="Play/Pause", command=play_pause)
btn_play.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  This is only related to stopping a timer and cancelling any pending updates.  It is not keeping up with the updates before I try and stop it.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more what you mean with keeping up with the updates? As far as I can tell it works exactly like your example does (just smooth).

Comment: If the background thread is sleeping 0.1 seconds every loop then it should display every tenth of a second.  Except it will jump from 2 seconds to 4 and then to 5, as an example.

Comment: Have you tried my code? It updates the display every 0.1 second.

Comment: Yes, just tried it.  It does work better.  I guess it is just the background loop that was causing the problem.  Seems like a quad core computer should be able to run 2 threads at once.

Comment: Python threads all run on a single core (unlike threads in other languages). I take it you didn't show the complete code and you are having issues integrating it? You probably don't need threads at all with tkinter, since the tkinter mainloop can do pretty much everything the threading module can do.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Most of my programming is in Java/Scala so when I created a thread I assumed it could use a separate processor.  So the background thread was just starving the main thread and it could not work smoothly.